# Solr 3.5 connectException

Tags: solr

I'm trying to upload Solr index from a CSV on a windows box to my Solr server on Linux. Using cygwin, my curl command look like this:

```
curl --max-time 3600 http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx/solr/update/csv -F commit=true -F stream.url=file://10.xxx.xxx.xxx/Users/testdata/sample.csv -F stream.contentType=text/plain -F fieldnames=partId,desc,category
```

The csv file in question is only about 4K in size, but I still get a connection timed out error.  These computers are on the same network, with no firewalls or proxy in the way.  The solr server is running on Tomcat 7 and I've increased the connectionTimeOut=3600000, but still not helping.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

additionally this is the error:

```
>HTTP Status 500 - Connection timed out

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.openServer(NetworkClient.java:118)
    at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:488)
    at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:475)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:270)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:352)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStreamBase$URLStream.getStream(ContentStreamBase.java:88)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStreamBase.getReader(ContentStreamBase.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.CSVLoader.load(CSVRequestHandler.java:355)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
```

again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this just to see if you can get it to update the data.

```
curl 'http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx/solr/update/csv?fieldnames=partId,desc,category' -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8' --data-binary [file_name]
```

This is a little simpler command than what you were using and may help identify what is going wrong. You may also want to check the Tomcat logs (/var/log/tomcat7) to see if there are any meaningful errors.

Comment: That helped, it showed another error that allowed me to fix the problem.  Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: @stirling Maybe you could at least upvote the helpful answer you got and add your own with the solution you've found.